# Get Columns Single Record in Stored Procedure Mysql

Tags: mysql, record, procedure

I have my procedure and is working, but my question is the following,
with the cursor is working correctly, but before the cursor I need a Single Record with several columns, I don´t know if I need another cursor just for one record.

Which would be the right way to get the columns of that single row without a cursor.

The query to execute is:

```
 'SELECT id,anio,fec_iniciointeres FROM mytable WHERE id=3 '
```

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `db`.`cal_intereses`$$

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `cal_intereses`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE factura_id INT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE val_avaluo DECIMAL(16,2);
    DECLARE fec_actual DATE;
    DECLARE done INT;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT  fac_facturas.id AS factura_id, fac_facturas.val_avaluo FROM fac_facturas WHERE  fac_facturas.vigencia_id<=26 AND  fac_facturas.estado=1 AND  fac_facturas.val_avaluo>0 LIMIT 10;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
    SET fec_actual=(SELECT CURDATE());

    SET done = 0;
    OPEN cur;
    ciclo: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO factura_id,val_avaluo;
    IF done=1 THEN LEAVE ciclo; END IF;
    DELETE FROM val_interesaux;
    IF fec_actual>='2006-07-29' THEN
    INSERT INTO val_interesaux(factura_id,fec_inicio) VALUES(factura_id,fec_actual);
    END IF;
    END LOOP ciclo;
    CLOSE cur;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```